# Knot to tie handle of a bag

Tags: knots

If you have full stuffed bag full of laundry with two handles, how would you tie the handles?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fold each handle into itself and treat each as a single strand.  Then just tie those two strands together in an ordinary square knot.

Here is an example showing a similar bag, although much smaller and with shorter handles.  The photos show things step by step: 1) pull the handles out into two doubled-over strands 2) right over left and under 3) left over right and under.

[image]
[image]
[image]